# Styling a photo to be the size of the element it is in

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

i have made this ListView, that has a photo in it:

[image]

this is a `<ul>` and each person is a `<li>`, inside each `<li>` there is a `<table>` and the photo is in one `<td>` and the name and the buttons are in the other `<td>`.

now as you can see the photo isnt the size of the `<li>`. it's smaller. the `<li>`'s height is determined by the name and the buttons size.

here is my code:

```
<ul style="width:250px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow:auto; max-height:100px;">
<asp:ListView ID="FriendRequests" runat="server" GroupItemCount="1" OnItemDataBound="FriendRequests_ItemDataBound">
<LayoutTemplate>
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #33b3b7; font-size:9px;">Friend Requests:</div>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</LayoutTemplate>
<GroupTemplate>
<li>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="top" >
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</tr>
</table>
</li>
</GroupTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<td title='<%# Eval("email") %>'>
<img style="border:1px solid gray"  Width="35px" Height="35px" src='<%# Eval("photo") %>' />
</td>
<td align="center" title='<%# Eval("email") %>'>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" CssClass="LinkToUser">
<span style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:underline;"><%# Eval("name") %></span><br />
</asp:HyperLink>
    <asp:Button ID="Accept" Font-Size="9px" runat="server" Text="Accept"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" Font-Size="9px" runat="server" Text="Deny"/>
</td>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I want that the photo's height will be the `height` of the `<li>` and the `width` to be the same as the `height`.

How can i do this?

*i only know javascript, html and asp.net so in your solution please use those. Thanks for the help

Comment: Give the image a height of 100% and set a size for its parent, but please do not use tables for this purpose, try achieving the same thing with divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

```
li {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;}

li img {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;}
```

Comment: Try to achieve it with jquery like so: $("img").css("width", $("img").parent().height());

Answer (score 2):

Give in image style as

```
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQL2v/5/). Though the image is invalid it has the width of the div it is contained in.

This will make the image as large as the container is or in other words the image will spread to 100% x 100% of the container.

Please let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: it does the height as the full height if the photo, which is like 300px. and i want the width and the height to be the same

Comment: @Cooper : sorry did not get you point in the comment above. Please explain or add the same in the question posted.